# (Cisco) ACL direction (in/out)?

Tags: cisco, acl

If I have an ACL, when applying it to an interface, I need to say "in" or "out". Is "in" referring to where the traffic is FROM, or where it is going TO?

Comment: You should also look carefully at the placement. In general, standard ACLs should be placed as close the the destination as possible, while extended ACLs should be placed as close to the source as possible.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terms IN and OUT are in reference to the router interface.  So IN means traffic coming into the router from that interface.  OUT means traffic leaving the router interface.